# How to get The Equal Number of Row for each Item in Where In Query (Mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, greatest-n-per-group

Suppose this is my Table

`Item | Name       | Price
----- ------------ --------
1    | Article    | 310.00
2    | Article    |  30.00
3    | Tips       | 150.00
4    | Tips       |  20.00
5    | NB         |  20.00`

My query

```
SELECT Item FROM Table WHERE NAME IN ('Article', 'Tips');
```

How Can I get only 1/2 row for each Item (Article & Tips)?

Comment: Wich rows do you want? Please show us the result that you expect.

Comment: Any Row. I mean random row but only 1/2 row for each item.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY rand()) as seqnum
      FROM Table t
      WHERE NAME IN ('Article', 'Tips')
     ) t
WHERE seqnum <= 1;
```

If you want 2 rows per item, you can change the "1" to "2".

If you want a particular item -- the newest or oldest or longest name or most red, you can change the `ORDER BY` -- assuming you have columns to represent what you want.

EDIT:

In older versions you can select  items using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.item <= coalesce( (select t2.item
                           from t t2
                           where t2.name = t.name
                           order by t2.item
                           limit 1 offset <n> - 1
                          ), t.item
                        );
```

Here is a [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fMTDkzVc9hTMbRJR5ULdMo/0).

Comment: Can you please check the demo here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jduKM9rRuJjMaSo5oWYtQi/2 . Is there anything wrong?

Comment: @TakiElias . . . Yes, you were running in MySQL 5.7.  Try this:  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jduKM9rRuJjMaSo5oWYtQi/2.

Comment: Hi, Can you please check your DB Fiddle link. May be You forgot to update your DB fiddle.

Comment: @TakiElias . . . I fixed that.

Comment: It's a great solution. Thanks a lot. But I need to join more than 3 tables. That is why I'm facing an error.

Answer (score 0):

A common solution is to filter with a correlated subquery. For example, this gives you the cheapest item per category:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
    t.name in ('Article', 'Tips')
    and t.price = (select min(price) from mytable t1 where t1.name = t.name)
```

If you want a *random* row:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
    t.name in ('Article', 'Tips')
    and t.id = (select id from mytable t1 where t1.name = t.name order by rand() limit 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use "distinct" modifier, as in

```
SELECT distinct NAME, sum(price) FROM Table WHERE NAME IN ('Article', 'Tips');
```

or 
    `SELECT distinct NAME, max(price) FROM Table WHERE NAME IN ('Article', 'Tips');`

Answer (score 0):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where name in ('Article', 'Tips')
and not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where name = t.name and item < t.item
)
```

this query will return the rows with the minimum `item`.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jduKM9rRuJjMaSo5oWYtQi/0).
Results:

```
| Item | Name    | Price |
| ---- | ------- | ----- |
| 1    | Article | 310   |
| 3    | Tips    | 150   |
```

Comment: If I want 2 rows?